# Agregar muchos datos de una a cloud firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, csv, google-cloud-firestore

que tal?
Estoy obteniendo los datos de csv usando papaparse y tengo un archivo de 15000 campos, hay alguna forma eficiente de agregar esa cantidad de documentos a cloud firestore sin que mi aplicacion falle?
A parte, hay limitaciones con firestore a la hora de escribir tanta cantidad de documentos?

Comment: Que haz intentado? Adjunta tu codigo

Comment: Probe usando el add de firestore unicamente, pero se toma un buen tiempo

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, si cuentas con el plan Spark gratuito, es probable que esa cantidad de filas supere la cuota gratuita. Te recomiendo leer bien los costos asociados: https://firebase.google.com/pricing

Respecto a tu problema, yo escribí un código Javascript simple en mi pc, que cargara todo por la forma estándar de firestore: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Lo que hice fue ir a la consola del proyecto en Firebase, en la pestaña _ Project Overview_ y al signo de agregar una aplicación. Ahí obtendrás un trozo de código que contiene las credenciales para acceder remotamente a la aplicación. Te adjunto un pequeño ejemplo:

```
const firebase = require ("firebase");
require("firebase/firestore");

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    measurementId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  };

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = firebase.firestore();
const colecRef = db.collection('ayudantes');

data = [//array con datos]

data.forEach((obj) =>{
    colecRef.add(obj).then(function(docRef){
        console.log("Se agrego: " + docRef.id)
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.log("Hubo un error al agregar: " + error);
    });
});
```

Para ejecutar ese código debes tener las dependencias instaladas localmente (se hace todo usando *npm*, node package manager). En mi caso, el array de datos lo tengo exportado desde otro archivo .js para mayor orden, considerando la cantidad de datos. Espero te sirva  !

Comment: Pero, yo tengo forma de agregar una gran cantidad de documentos de forma eficiente?